# react: How to change the state of a child component(function component, not class component) from its parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can change the state of child component which is `class componet` by `ref`,but how can I change the `function child compment`?

Comment: If you need to control the state of a child you should probably be holding the state in the parent to begin with, otherwise look at [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to pass a ref to a child and manage it that way.

Comment: Did you try to pass in the state as a property from parent? e.g. `<ChildComponent parentState={this.state.showTextInput />`

Comment: @pilchard Thank you first, I know `forwardRef`, I can attach the `ref` on the dom element in the child componet with `forwardRef`,but I want to change the state of child component, how to do it?

Comment: @JetCat Yes, I can lift the state to parent level, but is there any other way?

Comment: you can store anything in the passed `ref` including a function.

Comment: @pilchard sorry, I don't get your point,can you explain more clearly.

Comment: @pilchard Can you give me an code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using [`forwardRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) and storing the child's state handler function in the passed `ref` using the [`useImperativeHandle()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook allowing it to then be called from the parent.

```js
const App = () => {
  const childRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={childRef} />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => childRef.current.toggleRed()}>Toggle child</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [red, setRed] = React.useState(false);

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    toggleRed
  }));

  const toggleRed = () => {
    setRed(p => !p);
  }
  
  return (
    <div >
      <div className={`child ${red ? 'red' : 'gray'}`}></div>
    </div>
  );
})


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.red {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.gray {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you will need to pass the parent state in to child component as prop.

childComponent

```
export function ChildComponent(props) {

   return(
      <div> <p>You have clicked it {props.count} Times</p></div>
  )
}
```

parentComponent

```
import {ChildComponent} from './child.js'
function ParentComponent() {
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
return (
    <div>
        <ChildComponent count={count}/>
         <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a way, but i dont want lift the state. I just want to update the state of child component.

Comment: so you mean to say you don't need a value from Parent Component, but just want to update the state in child state component everytime Parent Component is called.

Comment: yes, parent call a `updateState function` which is defined in the child compoment, then update the state of child component.